# Translating cURL to IOS HTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, curl, httprequest

im sorry for the newbie question but im new to cURL and IOS, the question is:

How to translate these cURL calls to an IOS HTTPRequest?

curl https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/0 \

-H "Authorization: BoxAuth

api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&auth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

curl https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \

-H "Authorization: BoxAuth    api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&auth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

-F filename=@FILE_NAME \

-F folder_id=FOLDER_ID

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.